# Error while adding to cart, field keep null

Tags: laravel

i have a problem with addtocart function
it works fine but field color keep null ( no changes in it )

this is my function in CartController

```
public function AddToCart(request $request, $id){

        $res = array();
        $datalist = Product::where('id', $id)->first();
        $user = User::where('id', $datalist['user_id'])->first();

        $data = array();
        $data['id'] = $datalist['id'];
        $data['name'] = $datalist['title'];
        $data['qty'] = $request->qty;
        $data['price'] = $datalist['sale_price'];
        $data['weight'] = 0;
        $data['options'] = array();
        $data['options']['thumbnail'] = $datalist['f_thumbnail'];
        $data['options']['unit'] = $request->color;
        $data['options']['color'] = $request->size;
        $data['options']['seller_id'] = $datalist['user_id'];
        $data['options']['seller_name'] = $user['name'];
        $data['options']['store_name'] = $user['shop_name'];
        $data['options']['store_logo'] = $user['photo'];
        $data['options']['store_url'] = $user['shop_url'];
        $data['options']['seller_email'] = $user['email'];
        $data['options']['seller_phone'] = $user['phone'];
        $data['options']['seller_address'] = $user['address'];
```

and at ProductController i added this code:

```
    $color = $data->variation_color;
        $variation_color = explode(',', $color);
        
        $size = $data->variation_size;
        $variation_size = explode(',', $size);
```

cuz i have in my database products get two column ( variation_color, variation_size )

[as in pic:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzPIb.png)

and that's my code in product_blade.php

```
<div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="size">{{ __('المقاس') }}<span class="red">*</span></label>
                                            <select name="size" id="size" class="chosen-select form-control">
                                            @foreach($variation_size as $size)
                                                <option value="{{ $size }}">{{ $size }}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
```

really tested alot but cant get it to work, when i change
$data['options']['unit'] = $request->color;
to
$data['options']['unit'] = '1';

it show 1 in colomn, that mean i have problem with selection but i can't get it work

thanks

really tested alot but cant get it to work, when i change
$data['options']['unit'] = $request->color;
to
$data['options']['unit'] = '1';

it show 1 in colomn, that mean i have problem with selection but i can't get it work

thanks